# Can I use chinese iphone for debugging on xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, debugging

Is there a way to use Chinese iPhone that running ios for debugging on xcode while developing apps instead of apple iphones that more expensive ?

Comment: Ask Apple :-) :-) :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about using a counterfeit product.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The Chinese iPhones you're talking about are fake iPhones, they don't have iOS installed on them, they have some other operating system. So, they are something completely different form iPhone and this is why you can't.